# CheckBox on top of HERE MapFragment is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, checkbox, here-api

I am trying to put some additional controls on top of the FrameLayout. 
Buttons are showing but for checkbox is not. 
I can see the checkbox showing before the map is loading but after that it is gone.

Here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   ---EDIT---
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
   ---EDIT---
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_address"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/action_search"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="#2a2dc7"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Show Risk"
        android:id="@+id/show_risk_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_zoom_in"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_zoom_out"
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_current_location"
        android:text="Location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use DDMS and dump the layout of your app? Probably some android layout issue?

Comment: i added new layout inside the frame_layout. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a new layout inside the frame layout.